# How add a general listener for all buttons (no intrusive)?

Tags: android

I try to play a sound when you push any button of the app.

How is the minor intrusive way to add the listener to all buttons in the app?

Can I add overwrite (and extend) the generic listener of Android?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a custom Button by extending Button class and set Listener there

Comment: or use xml for this:
android:onClick="someMethod"

in your layout-xml, give all buttons the onClick attribute.
Then in your activity, create a Method: someMethod,
and all buttons will call this by a click

Comment: But this ways are intrusives, I would like no have touch my old listeners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set one listener for all buttons and can be identified with tag also.

```
View.OnClickListener myClickLIstener= new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String tag = (String) v.getTag();
        Log.e("","tag : "+tag)
       // your stuff
    }
};
```

setting up listeners...

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(myClickLIstener);
btn1.setTag("btn1");
btn2.setOnClickListener(myClickLIstener);
btn2.setTag("btn2");
```

**EDIT :**

Are you looking for like this...

```
class superTop implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("", "onClick superTop");
        }

    }

    class NewClick extends superTop implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("", "onClick NewClick");

            super.onClick(v);

        }

    }

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new NewClick());
```

You can call both the listener...

Comment: But this ways are intrusives, I would like no have touch my old listeners.

Comment: If you want to override or extend listener then it's not possible because listeners are `interface`. You have to make custom interface for that and call them from btnclickListener. If have comman functionality for stuff then make base class and extend it. This can help you.

Comment: Could you implement View.OnClickListener? In your implementation MyOnClickListener define your own onClick() method with generic behavior and then in the activity MyOnClickListener myClickListener= new MyOnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) { super.onclick();
        String tag = (String) v.getTag();
        Log.e("","tag : "+tag)
       // your stuff
    }

Comment: Yes something like that. It´s little intrusive. But will be better in Android exists easy way to generate a common behaviour. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

OR JUST

```
class YourClass implements OnClickListener{
    buttonOne.setOnclickListener(this);
    buttonTwo.setOnclickListener(this);
    buttonThree.setOnclickListener(this);

    public void onClick(View v){
        //do your stuff;
    }
}
```

Or if you like, make your custom Button :

```
Class Yourbutton extends Button implements Button.OnClickListener{
    public Yourbutton(Context c) {
        super(c);
    }
    public Yourbutton(Context c,AttributeSet s){
        super(c,s);
    }
    public void onClick(View v){
        //do your stuff;
    }
}
```

So now you can use Yorkbutton as the generic button that does the generic jobs.

Comment: But this ways are intrusives, I would like no have touch my old listeners.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this first let your class implement the OnClickListener

```
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

In the onClick method do the following:

```
public void onClick(View view) {


    switch(view.getId()){

//here you need the id of the button i.e. its id in the xml file
    case R.id.button1:
        // do whatever you want button1 to do
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        // do whatever you want button2 to do
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `android:onClick` attribute. Set the same onClick method to all of them like this:

```
<Button
[...]
android:onClick="handleButton"/>

<Button
[...]
android:onClick="handleButton"/>
```

And in your java file:

```
public void handleButton(View v){
// do some stuff
}
```

Comment: But this ways are intrusives, I would like no have touch my old listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Create one click Listener like this and call it from all your buttons if want them to do the same

```
View.OnClickListener yourClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //play the music
        }
    };
```

Then call that listener

```
button1.setOnClickListener(yourClickListener);
button2.setOnClickListener(yourClickListener);
button3.setOnClickListener(yourClickListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call same methods of the buttons you want to work same like

```
<LinearLayout ...>
  <Button android:text="1" onClick="onButtonClicked" clickable="true" />
  <Button android:text="2" onClick="onButtonClicked" clickable="true" />
  <Button android:text="3" onClick="onButtonClicked" clickable="true" />
  <Button android:text="4" onClick="onButtonClicked" clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Above four buttons have different text but onClick they are having the same method now there is no need to get them in java class using findViewById.

In the activity where the layout is shown just add a method

```
public void onButtonClicked(View v){
     // do whatever needs to be done. For example:
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((Button) v).getText() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```

**Second Method**

You need not repeat same code for all. You can try out a generic listener, like :

```
private OnClickListener genericClickListener= new OnClickListener() { 
    public void Click(View v) {
            // do something
    } 
};
```

Then all you have to do is register all three buttons to use this genericClickListener. That is, inside `onCreate()`,

```
Button firstbtn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstbtn); 
Button secondbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secondbtn); 
Button thirdbtn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.thirdbtn); 

firstbtn.setOnClickListener(genericClickListener);
secondbtn.setOnClickListener(genericClickListener);
thirdbtn.setOnClickListener(genericClickListener);
```

**Third Method**

Create a single function/method and **onClick** of all the button calls the same `Method/Function`.