# How to display toast message in an alert dialog box?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, toast

I wanted to write a program such that when I click the Ok button, a message is displayed in toast, for clicking on the Ok button of that alert dialog box. But, this case turned out to be pretty different. I don't know what should I put as the first argument in makeText().
Apparently 'this' is not the desired parameter to the argument context.
This is the code I wrote:

```
package com.example.spinner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void click (View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder ad= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad.setTitle("Alert Window");
        ad.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ad.setMessage("This is an alert dialog box");
        MyListener m= new MyListener();
        ad.setPositiveButton("OK", m);
        ad.show();
    }
}

class MyListener implements OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You selected OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using getApplicationContext() or MainActivity.this or did you get any error while passing above parameter as a argument.

Comment: I have posted the answer please check it and let me know whether it is working or not

Comment: Since I'm using another class MyListener MainActivity.this isn't working.

Comment: are you getting the alert box?

Comment: yes, I'm getting the alert box.

Comment: Please have look at below links
http://tekeye.biz/2012/code-android-event-listeners
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923184/how-add-a-general-listener-for-all-buttons-no-intrusive

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
Toast.makeText(this, "You selected OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

with

```
 Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "You selected OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 AlertDialog ad= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    ad.setTitle("Alert Window");
    ad.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    ad.setMessage("This is an alert dialog box");
    ad.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You selected OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    //ad is the object reference
            ad.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You selected ok",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```